# jQuery - Multiple textareas counting characters only updates first one in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating multiple `textareas` on a page, however only one is shown at a time.

The issue is I want to be able to **update** multiple `spans`, from multiple `textarea`s so that I can keep a single function.  Is there a way to possibly use `$(this)`?  I know there is a way to accomplish this .. I'm just not seeing it!

HERE IS THE [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uxqderxa/)

```js
$('.send_message_text').bind('input propertychange', function (e) {

    var tval = $('.send_message_text').val(),
            tlength = tval.length,
            set = 1024,
            remain = parseInt(set - tlength);
    $('.chars_left').text(remain);
    if (remain <= 0 && e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
        $('.send_message_text').val((tval).substring(0, tlength - 1));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="send_invite_text" class="send_message_text"></textarea>
<textarea id="send_message_text" class="send_message_text"></textarea>


<div class="chars_left_wrapper">
<span class="chars_left">1024</span>
<span> characters remaining</span>
</div>
<div class="chars_left_wrapper">
<span class="chars_left">1024</span>
<span> characters remaining</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `bind` event, you're calling for the first available `textarea`. You need to use the one that triggered the event.

Here's the solution:

```
$('.send_message_text').bind('input propertychange', function (e) {
     var tval = $(e.currentTarget).val(),
            tlength = tval.length,
            set = 1024,
            remain = parseInt(set - tlength);
    $('.chars_left').text(remain);
    if (remain <= 0 && e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
        $('.send_message_text').val((tval).substring(0, tlength - 1));
    }
});
```

Comment: `currentTarget` is exactly what I was looking for .. Thank you for explaining this!

Answer (score 2):

A solution with $(this):

```
$('.send_message_text').bind('input propertychange', function (e) {
     var tval = $(this).val(),
            tlength = tval.length,
            set = 1024,
            remain = parseInt(set - tlength);
    $('.chars_left').text(remain);
    if (remain <= 0 && e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
        $(this).val((tval).substring(0, tlength - 1));
    }
});
```